# index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm getting the above error but not sure why as I'm sure their is something in the array. I first declared a `NSMutableArray` in a .h file. In the .m file where I create the scene I create a texture and add it to the array like this:

```
texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"obstacle"];
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:texture];
```

Through out the rest of my code i have methods that use this array to create a sprite node:

```
SKSpriteNode *obstacle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Which works, I can see the image `obstacle` for these sprite nodes. But at the end of the scene, when I try to `[array removeAllObjects];`, I get the above error. How is there nothing in the array when my `SKSpriteNode` was just drawing a texture from it?

Comment: Are you using ARC? Is it declared as strong?

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that you're misunderstanding object ownership. You're creating an `SKTexture` object and passing around the *pointer* (or *reference*) to that object. This is what you're doing:

1. Create `SKTexture` object and keep a reference to it in `array`, which retains the object.
2. Create an `SKSpriteNode` object using the above texture, which may retain or copy it (I'm not sure, and if you don't know the difference then you need to learn the basics of memory management).
3. Remove all the objects (actually you're removing the references) from `array`, which releases them (but may not destroy them).

After step 3, the texture still exists in the `SKSpriteNode` but there's no longer a reference to it in `array`. So if after step 3 you try to access any index from `array`, you're trying to access beyond the bounds of the array and that's what's triggering your crash.

Comment: I kinda follow what your saying, i've never read thuroughly on memory management as this is my first coding project. What i wanted with the array was to load a image for when i need it and to completely get rid of it when the scene changes, to not have it retained it memory, thus leading to a unending rise in memory. How can i fix what i have to completely rid the array, to release and destroy any object in it?

Comment: Make your life easier by making each scene keep an array of (i.e. responsible for) its textures. It will automatically destroy all its children and the array when it's removed and destroyed.

Comment: This is the only scene that uses an array or any textures, and when the scene does change, the array isn't releasing anything. I can tell because when i run instruments, the SKSpriteNode i have above just keeps climbing in memory, it loads the texture, but it never gets released.

Comment: Then you're not releasing the `SKSpriteNode`. If you really want more help then you're going to have to post more code. You can do so by editing your answer above.

Comment: I'll create another question, as it really doesn't relate to the one asked here.